# Java generics -- looking for a method to tell me the supertype of a generic type

Tags: java, generics

the supertype of

```
SomeClass <Double>
```

is

```
Someclass <T extends Numbers>
```

and is not

```
SomeClass <Numbers>
```

i'm looking for a method returning the supertype of an instance of a generic class. Something like 
`getGenericSuperclass()` of the of `Class` ( although can't be exactly like it-- 
`getGenericSuperclass()` returns only one class while a generic can extend and be bounded by multiple as in:

Eg.:

```
Someclass <T extends aConcreteClass && anInterface && anotherInterface>
```

When i run `getGenericSuperclass()` on an instance of a generic class, i'm getting `Object` in return.

Is there such a method anywhere in Java, telling me the supertype of the generic type on which i instantiated an object on?

//===================

EDIT:  lengthy comment to @jwa's answer below:

i understand the generics are type-checked at compile time. 
however, JVM could still bind the types in run-time, as specifically as possible 
using the outcome of [type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), and return at least the definition of the supertype 
rather than merely returning **Object** as the supertype. This info is clearly available 
in runtime. but i gather it's not doing this.

NOTE: haven't yet looked deep into type erasure.

//=================================

EDIT2:

referring to the term "bounded type parameter" 
in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) page, 
i've been looking for a method to return the object's "bound class(es)",

which is **Comparable** in the example

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private T data;
private Node<T> next;

public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}

public T getData() { return data; }
// ...
}
```

on the same [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).

no trace of it in those pages or anywhere else-- i guess Java not doing it.

Comment: Just becasue A is a supertype of B does not mean X<A> is a supertype of X<B>

Comment: @Ingo great line. now read what the Q is asking.

Comment: I am telling you that the assumption the question rests upon is wrong. Like in: The father of a person is a daemon, and not an alligator. Is there a function to identify the daemon that is the father of some given person?

Comment: To comment your 2nd edit, `i've been looking for a method to return the object's "bound class(es)",`, there is no such method. The reason for that is that knowing the bound would not help you at runtime, you could not use it in any meaningful way, because of type erasure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take a look into "type erasure". Essentially, when your java code is compiled into bytecode the generic information is lost (or "erased"). This is why you cannot find any methods for querying the generic typing via the reflection classes.

I couldn't find a good answer regarding type erasure here on SO, but Wikiepdia seems to have a [reasonable description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure).

It's worth noting that type erasure was chosen to give backward-compatability between java 1.5 and 1.4. Other languages have implemented this differently. For example, .NET has full support for generics in byte code - and does permit such methods as part of its reflection API.

---

Consider this class, which uses typed and non-typed lists:

```
import java.util.List;

public class CastExample <T extends Object> {
    public List<T> typedList;
    public List<?> untypedList;

    public T getFirstElement() {
        return typedList.get(0);
    }


    public T getFromUntypedArray() {
        return (T) untypedList.get(0);
    }
}
```

There is no difference between the way that the two methods are encoded in byte code. We can see this using `javap`, specifically `javap -c CastExample`:

```
/var/tmp-> javap -c CastExample

Compiled from "CastExample.java"
public class CastExample<T> {
  public java.util.List<T> typedList;

  public java.util.List<?> untypedList;

  public CastExample();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public T getFirstElement();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: getfield      #2                  // Field typedList:Ljava/util/List;
       4: iconst_0      
       5: invokeinterface #3,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
      10: areturn       

  public T getFromUntypedArray();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: getfield      #4                  // Field untypedList:Ljava/util/List;
       4: iconst_0      
       5: invokeinterface #3,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
      10: areturn       
}
```

The exact meaning of each of these operations is not overly important. The important thing is that it is calling the exact same operations, there's no distinction between the two.

Comment: Thx for the useful answer. pls see my my comment in "EDIT" below //================ in the Q.

Comment: @Roam Just to stress, when the code is written out to bytecode, all the references to the type parameters are written as Object. No trace of generics exist in the bytecode. If this is your own class, then you could take `Class<T>` in your constructor - which would require you to pass in the class you are going to use. You could subsequently call a getter on this value to get the type of the class.

Comment: can use the object in its generic type without casting back from the type Object. so there is some more in between. it clearly can distinguish the generic's raw type for one thing.

Comment: @Roam There is no additional information in the bytecode. It is only the compiler than can ascertain the generic type. I've edited my answer to try and illustrate this with `javap`. I hope it helps to clarify - don't focus too much on what the operations are in the byte code, just note that they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

> the supertype of
>
> SomeClass `<Double>`   is
>
> Someclass `<T extends Numbers>`

The premise of the question is wrong. First of all, `Someclass <T extends Numbers>` is not syntactically correct as a type in Java.

And second, there is no single generic "supertype" of a type. The following is a list of some (but not all) supertypes of `SomeClass <Double>`:

```
SomeClass<? extends Number>
SomeClass<? extends Serializable>
SomeClass<? extends Comparable<Double>>
SomeClass<? extends Comparable<? extends Number>>
SomeClass<? extends Comparable<? extends Serializable>>
SomeClass<? extends Comparable<? extends Comparable<Double>>>
SomeClass<? extends Comparable<?>>
SomeClass<? extends Object>
SomeClass<?>
SomeClass<? super Double>
Object
(and if SomeClass has a superclass or interface SuperclassOfSomeClass:)
SuperclassOfSomeClass<Double>
SuperclassOfSomeClass<? extends Number>
... (all of the above for SomeClass repeated for SuperclassOfSomeClass, etc.)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeap, generics aren't covariant in Java, i.e **List< Number >** is not a superclass of **List< Double >**. You should read some info on it, heres a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).